# Yii2- php - mkdir with space error

Tags: php, yii2

I googling about this problem ,but have no result

Assume that a newbie want to create a folder with space like "My Pics" 
( It's not good practice but it is)
And I try to escape space :

```
            $path = str_replace(" ", "\\ ", realpath($folder);
            mkdir($path,0755,true);
```

But I get an error :

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

mkdir(): Protocol error
```

If I using system() , It work well but I don't want run directly system command in my PHP program.

Please help me correcting my issue

Thanks

Comment: Show what's in $path variable before mkdir execution, also try without third parameter true and also you should check whether apache or nginx user have enough permissions.

Comment: As I said in question , if I replace with system command , it work well , third parameter or not is still get error

Comment: It is a php [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39485)

Comment: It's very old information and nobody else confirmed. What OS and php version are you using?

Comment: My god , I solved my problem , when using mkdir , you no need to escape space

Answer (score 0):

My god , I solved my problem , when using mkdir , you no need to escape space

```
        $path = realpath($folder);
        mkdir($path,0755,true);
```